# Entity Framework Code First property with a different name from the convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have the following setup using Entity Framework Code First:-

```
public Player
{
    [Key]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    public int? ClubId { get; set; }
    public virtual Club Club { get; set; }
}

public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to rename the property 'Club' in the 'Player' class to 'CurrentClub', as it makes more sense in my application, however this fails as it doesn't follow the naming convention that EF uses out of the box.

How can I rename the property successfully?

From what I've seen, I thought I could use the [ForeignKey("Name")] attribute, however I can't find a reference for it. I can see posts saying that it has moved namespace....but I still can't find it. I'm using .NET 4.0, but have .NET 4.5 installed on my machine.

Is the ForeignKey attribute the correct way to do it, or do I need to do some model binding? If so, what do I need?

Comment: Can you try putting `[ForeignKey("ClubId")]` on `public virtual Club Club { get; set; }` then put `[Column("Club")]` on `public virtual Club CurrentClub { get; set; }`

Comment: I don't have the ForeignKey attribute available to me for some reason. The .NET 4.0 DLL for DataAnnotations doesn't have it. (That I can find)

Comment: What namespaces are you using?

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

Comment: I was wondering why I didnt have that. Turns out, I didn't have EntityFramework installed in my project. My domain objects are in a separate project from my DBContext... Thus my confusion.
I installed the package through Nuget, and used your attributes recommendation, and it works! Thanks for your help.